# Golang: MongoDB Double Type cannot decode into Float64

Tags: mongodb, go

Currently running into an issue where the mongodb double type cannot decode into a float64 and its saying that its a string
This is the error:

```
2022/08/02 14:24:02 error decoding key imdb.rating: cannot decode string into a float32 or float64 type
```

and this is what the imdb struct looks like:

```
    type Imdb struct {
    Rating float64 `bson:"rating,truncate"`
    Votes  int32   `bson:"votes,omitempty"`
    Id     int32   `bson:"id,omitempty"`
}
```

this is part of a bigger struct called movie as shown here:

```
type Movie struct {
    Id           primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Plot         string             `bson:"plot,omitempty"`
    Genres       []string           `bson:"genres,omitempty"`
    Runtime      int32              `bson:"runtime,omitempty"`
    Rated        string             `bson:"rated,omitempty"`
    Title        string             `bson:"title,omitempty"`
    Poster       string             `bson:"poster,omitempty"`
    Countries    []string           `bson:"countries,omitempty"`
    FullPlot     string             `bson:"fullplot,omitempty"`
    CommentCount int32              `bson:"num_mflix_comments,omitempty"`
    Cast         []string           `bson:"cast,omitempty"`
    Directors    []string           `bson:"directors,omitempty"`
    Writers      []string           `bson:"writers,omitempty"`
    Awards       Award              `bson:"awards,omitempty"`
    Updated      string             `bson:"lastupdated,omitempty"`
    Year         int32              `bson:"year,omitempty"`
    Imdb         Imdb               `bson:"imdb,omitempty"`
    Type         string             `bson:"type,omitempty"`
    Tomatoes     Tomato             `bson:"tomatoes,omitempty"`
}
```

[Example MongoDB Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUXxu.png)

```
func GetMovies() []Movie {
    var movies []Movie
    db := config.GetDb()
    movieCollection := db.Collection("movies")
    curr, err := movieCollection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err = curr.All(context.Background(), &movies); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return movies
}
```

Comment: You must not leave a space before the option: `\`bson:"rating,truncate"\``

Comment: mmm ok thanks! I fixed that but still no good

Comment: Are you sure it"s double in DB and not a string? Please post an example document, and the Go code that performs the query.

Comment: Just updated with document and calling code

Comment: Your example works for me with or without the `,truncate` option. What do you get if you enter `typeof db.movies.findOne().imdb.rating` in the mongo shell?

Comment: Also what version of the driver do you use? Please try to update to the latest version and try with that too. And what version of MongoDB do you have?

Comment: Also what do you get if you run `db.movies.aggregate({$project:{rating_type:{$type:"$imdb.rating"}}})` in the mongo shell?

Comment: let me try those real quick and see what I get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247009/discussion-between-kiran-and-icza).

Comment: So I found a solution but its not the best and I think my results will be mixed but I had to do `interface{}` for the whole Imdb struct and the Year field in the Movie struct to get it to work. I think its because the fields are not in the same order for some of the documents in the db